# How to construct this JSON array of JSONObjects

Tags: java, json

I have a Problem which I have to solve in Java.I have a data in YAML where the data is in this structure

```
600450:
  STATE:STATE1
  CITY:CITY1
  ID:1
  CONTACT:1234
600453:
  STATE:STATE1
  CITY:CITY1
  ID:2
  CONTACT:3456
600451:
  STATE:STATE2
  CITY:CITY2 
  ID:3
  CONTACT:2234
.....
```

I converted this into JSONObject but I am strugling to change this into this JSONObject object where the structure should be of this form

```
{
  STATE1:
        {[
           CITY1:{
                    [{ID:1,CODE:600450,CONTACT:1234}, 
                     {ID:2,CODE:600453,CONTACT:3456}
                    ]
                 },
           CITY2:{
                    [
                      {ID:3,CODE:600451,CONTACT:1234}
                    ]
                 }
        ]}
}
```

I have almost lost a hour by doing different Things with JSONObject and JSONArray and then switched to HashMap and ArrayList of HashMap but I am not able to get it ! 
This was my try I am sure this is absurd I know that How to achieve this in Java .

Comment: Share some code, in the question and not as a link, and explain what/where the issue is with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your converted initial JSON looks like this:

```js
{
    "600450": {
        "STATE": "STATE1",
        "CITY": "CITY1",
        "ID": 1,
        "CONTACT": 1234
    },
    "600451": {
        "STATE": "STATE2",
        "CITY": "CITY2",
        "ID": 3,
        "CONTACT": 2234
    },
    "600453": {
        "STATE": "STATE1",
        "CITY": "CITY1",
        "ID": 2,
        "CONTACT": 3456
    }
}
```

Here is a static method that does the full conversion to your desired format:

```java
static JSONObject convert(JSONObject initial) {
        // STATE -> CITY -> Address[]
        Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>> stateToCityToAddresses = new HashMap<>();

        // Get list of codes
        String[] codes = JSONObject.getNames(initial);

        // Loop over codes - "600450", "600451", "600453", ...
        for (String code : codes) {

            // Get the JSONObject containing state data
            JSONObject state = initial.getJSONObject(code);

            // Extract information from state JSONObject
            String stateName = state.getString("STATE");
            String cityName = state.getString("CITY");
            long id = state.getLong("ID");
            long contact = state.getLong("CONTACT");

            // Some Java 8 awesomeness!
            List<Map<String, Object>> addresses = stateToCityToAddresses
                .computeIfAbsent(stateName, sn -> new HashMap<>()) // This makes sure that there is a Map available to hold cities for a given state
                .computeIfAbsent(cityName, cn -> new ArrayList<>()); // This makes sure that there is a List available to hold addresses for a given city

            // Save data in a map representing a json object like: {"CONTACT":1234,"CODE":600450,"ID":1}
            Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<>();
            address.put("ID", id);
            address.put("CONTACT", contact);
            address.put("CODE", Long.parseLong(code));

            // Add the address under city
            addresses.add(address);
        }

        // Just use the JSONObject.JSONObject(Map<?, ?>) constructor to get the final result
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(stateToCityToAddresses);

        // You can sysout the result to see the data
        // System.out.println(result);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to play Devil's Advocate.

I think you may risk deviating away from the relationships that have been described in the `.yaml`. You should try to avoid embedding any application-specific logic inside of your data models, since your assumptions may land you in trickier places in the future.

Generally speaking, you should respect the initial form of the data and interpret the relationships or associated logic with the flexibility of runtime processing. Otherwise, you end up serializing data structures which do not correlate directly with the source, and your assumptions may land you in a hot spot.

The "real" JSON equivalent, I suspect; would look something like this:

```
{
  "600450": {
    "STATE": "STATE1",
    "CITY": "CITY1",
    "ID": 1,
    "CONTACT": 1234
  },
  "600453": { ...etc }
}
```

It would still be possible to pair these relationships. If you want to relate all Objects by city, you could first separate them into bins. You could do this by using a `Map` which relates a `String` city to a `List` of `JSONObject`s:

```
// This will be a Map of List of JSONObjects separated by the City they belong to.
final Map<String, List<JSONObject>> mCityBins = new ArrayList();
// Iterate the List of JSONObjects.
for(final JSONObject lJSONObject : lSomeListOfJSONObjects) {
  // Fetch the appropriate bin for this kind of JSONObject's city.
  List<JSONObject> lBin = mCityBins.get(lJSONObject.get("city"));
  // Does the right bin not exist yet?
  if (lBin ==  null) {
    // Create it!
    lBin = new ArrayList();
    // Make sure it is in the Map for next time!
    mCityBins.add(lJSONObject.get("city"), lBin);
  }
  // Add the JSONObject to the selected bin.
  lBin.add(lJSONObject);
}
```

Whilst you process the `JSONObject`s, whenever you come across a city whose key does not exist in the `Map`, you can allocate a new `List<JSONObject>`, add the current item to that `List` and add it into the `Map`. For the next `JSONObject` you process, if it belongs to the same city, you'd find the existing `List` to add it to.

Once they're separated into bins, generating the corresponding JSON will be easy!

Answer (score 0):

As I see your git repo you just try to convert first Json structure to new Structure you want. I must to tell you probably you could create this structure directly from YAML file.
As I don't see your first Json structure so I guess that must be something like this :

```
{600450:{STATE:STATE1 , CITY:CITY2 , ...} ,  ...}
```

If this is true so this way can help you :

```
    public static JSONObject convert(JSONObject first) throws JSONException {
    HashMap<String , HashMap<String , JSONArray>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<String> keys = first.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext())
    {
        String key = keys.next();
        JSONObject inner = first.getJSONObject(key);
        String state = inner.getString("STATE");
        HashMap<String , JSONArray> stateMap =
                hashMap.computeIfAbsent(state , s -> new HashMap<>());

        String city = inner.getString("CITY");
        JSONArray array = stateMap.computeIfAbsent(city , s->new JSONArray());
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
        o.put("ID" , inner.getInt("ID"));
        //in this section you could create int key by calling Integer.parse(String s);
        o.put("CODE" , Integer.valueOf(key));
        o.put("CONTACT" , inner.getInt("CONTACT"));
        array.put(o);

    }

    JSONObject newStructureObject = new JSONObject();
    for(String stateKey:hashMap.keySet())
    {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject cityObject = new JSONObject();
        HashMap<String , JSONArray> cityMap = hashMap.get(stateKey);
        for(String cityKey : cityMap.keySet())
        {
            cityObject.put(cityKey , cityMap.get(cityKey));

        }
        array.put(cityObject);
        newStructureObject.put(stateKey , array);
    }

    return newStructureObject;
}
```